# What's the supremum and infimum of the set $M=\left \{ \left ( -\frac{1}{3} \right )^{m}-\frac{5}{n}\mid m,n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> What's the supremum and infimum of the set $M=\left \{ \left (
> -\frac{1}{3} \right )^{m}-\frac{5}{n}\mid m,n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$
>
> Are they included in the set?

$$\inf = \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1}-\frac{5}{1} = -\frac{16}{3}$$

It's obviously included in the set for $m=1$ and $n=1$ which also means that the infimum is a minimum.

$$\sup=\lim_{m,n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \left (
-\frac{1}{3} \right )^{m}-\frac{5}{n}  \right )=0$$

The supremum isn't in the set.

I have my doubts how I solved this... Is it correct?

Comment: The infimum and supremum don't need to be in the set.  They need to bound it.  I have the $\inf M =  - 5 \frac 13$, and $\sup M =\frac 19.$

Comment: The first is right, the second  is not. Let $m=2$ and $n$ very big.

Comment: Thank you very much! And nice rep André never seen so high!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make $\left( -\tfrac 1 3 \right)^m - \tfrac 5 n$ as large as possible, you  need $m$ to be even so that the negative sign is killed and also as small as possible since as $m$ gets large $\left( \tfrac 1 3 \right)^m$ gets small. Thus we should take $m=2$. However, to ensure that we aren't subtracting off too much, we would like $n$ to be as large as possible. Indeed, setting $m=2$ and taking $n\to \infty$ gives that the supremum is $\tfrac 1 9$. The supremum is not a member of the set in this case since it required taking $n\to\ \infty$ (i.e., it is never actually achieved for finite $n$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification, understood! :-)